# Keep getting insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost, when trying to send a pre-signed transaction for account abstraction transaction

Tags: solidity, hardhat, erc-4337, account-abstraction

**Problem:**
I am starting to explore [account-abstraction](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction) and trying to run all the unit tests. Right now I am getting error in [`should deploy the factory`](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/5e78f8635552e3c55fbced072056a77c8f1e8b75/test/create2factory.test.ts#L14) test when trying to execute it on a private test `evm` network. When I run the same test against `ganache` or test hardhat network, it runs successfully.

The error I got when running against my private test network:

> Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See:
> https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ]
> (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError:
> HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request
> (/Users/asad/Dev/caduceus/Account-Abstraction/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)\n
> at HDWalletProvider.request
> (/Users/asad/Dev/caduceus/Account-Abstraction/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:187:34)\n
> at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async
> EthersProviderWrapper.send
> (/Users/asad/Dev/caduceus/Account-Abstraction/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true},
> method="sendTransaction",
> transaction="0xf8a58085174876e800830186a08080b853604580600e600039806000f350fe7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe03601600081602082378035828234f58015156039578182fd5b8082525050506014600cf31ba02222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222a02222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
> code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.7.2)

Although I deposit enough funds to the signer as well as the wallet i am running the test with.

**More Questions:**

- The test, `should deploy the factory` is sending an already signed transaction, which ensure deployment of contract to a pre-computed address. Is this necessary to deploy this particular contract to the same address?
- What does this particular contract (deployed by `should deploy the factory` test) do and where can we find source code for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about this test case :

```
  it('should deploy the factory', async () => {
    expect(await factory._isFactoryDeployed()).to.equal(false, 'factory exists before test deploy')
    await factory.deployFactory()
    expect(await factory._isFactoryDeployed()).to.equal(true, 'factory failed to deploy')
  })
```

Then : its only checking the factory deployment.

Comment: No. It checks whether factory is deployed or not and deploys if factory is not deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Test tests are meant to run on local network. they were tested to work on local hardhat and geth

It is a [standard deterministic deployer](https://github.com/Arachnid/deterministic-deployment-proxy), not directly related to ERC-4337.
The deployer is created from address 0x3fab184622dc19b6109349b94811493bf2a45362, so you can try to fund it and see if it works.

Comment: I tried multiple times to deploy the contract. I have funded the deployer address with sufficient balance, more than 150 ETHs. But still I get the same error.